# How to add Wi-Fi option in GPRS spinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

In my application i am using "apn" for GPRS connection display. I code a spinner in which i get the Telenor GPRS, Telenor MMS and Telenor WAP.
**I want to add Wi-Fi option in this spinner. and when i select Wi-Fi option device start sensing Wi-Fi.

Q: How can i add option of Wi-Fi in my spinner??
**
This is my Code

```
Spinner GPRS;
String [] name_of_GPRS__available;
int [] apn_id;         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.configuration); 

    EnumerateAPNs();

   /* this is a android enviroment in which you can develop an android application in which you 
    * share all your basic necessities of thrkife bghhr4y2ghrrr*/

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    GPRS = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.GPRS);
            ArrayAdapter<?> spinner_array = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,name_of_GPRS__available);
    spinner_array.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());     
    Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();     
    prefsEditor.putString("Object", name_of_GPRS__available.toString());  
    prefsEditor.commit(); 
    GPRS.setAdapter(spinner_array);
    //GPRS.setOnItemSelectedListener(MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    GPRS.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());`

    GPRS.setAdapter(spinner_array);
    //GPRS.setOnItemSelectedListener(MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    GPRS.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
          final int position, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
      SetDefaultAPN(apn_id[position]);

          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "ETracking System Selects " +          
      parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
      }


        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }

      public boolean SetDefaultAPN(int id)
      {
          boolean res = false;
          ContentResolver resolver = Configuration.this.getContentResolver();
          ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

          values.put("apn_id", id); 
          try
          {
              resolver.update(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn"), values, null, null);
              Cursor c = resolver.query(
                    Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn"), 
                      null, 
                      "_id="+id, 
                      null, 
                      null);
              if(c != null)
              {
                  res = true;
                  c.close();
              }
          }
          catch (SQLException e)
          {
              //Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());
          }
           return res;

      }

    /*
       * Enumerate all APN data
       */
      private void EnumerateAPNs()
      {
          Cursor   c = this.getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/current"), null, null, null, null);
          if (c != null) 
          {

              //String s = "All APNs:\n";
              //Log.d("TAG", s);
                try 
              {
                   printAllData(c); //Print the entire result set
              }
                catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Configuration.this, "No Network Connection Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

              c.close();
          }

      }


      /*
       *  Print all data records associated with Cursor c.
       *  Return a string that contains all record data.
       *  For some weird reason, Android SDK Log class cannot print very long string message.
       *  Thus we have to log record-by-record.
       */
      private void printAllData(Cursor c)
      {
          //if(c == null) return null;


          if(c.moveToFirst())
          {
            name_of_GPRS__available = new String[c.getCount()];
            apn_id = new int [c.getCount()];
            int i= 0;

            do{

                    name_of_GPRS__available [i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    apn_id[i]=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    //Log.d("TAG",name[i]);
                    i++;

              }while(c.moveToNext());
              //Log.d("TAG","End Of Records");

            //name_of_GPRS_available [1]=" GPRS";

          }   
      }
```

Kindly guide me. How can i do it. I'll be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is for a Gingerbread Device as Setting the Default APN was removed in ICS (4.0 - API 14), deprecated.

Have you tried adding in:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

You will need to add these permissions to your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

You can also have an additional `Spinner` come up to have the User select from available Wifi spots by using Scan Result: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html

and then

WifiManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

to set the Desired Network if there is not a default connection in place.

Markana has a nice tutorial on using Wifi this way: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html